Why does this LM317T regulator's output voltage decrease when using a variable resistor for R2 but not while using a fixed resistor?
I have connected an LM317T regulator circuit according to the following schematic:

The above schematic is from "https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/lab/LM317.pdf"; I added the diode.
When I use a fixed resistor for R2, the output voltage is stable.  When I use a variable resistor (a multi-turn, or a potentiometer) for R2 the output voltage keeps decreasing.
Postscript:
In trying to find the cause of the problem, I measured my variable resistors with an ohmmeter. Their value decreases 0.1 Ω per 50-60 seconds.  This causes the output voltage of the LM317T to decrease.
Why does the value of these variable resistors decrease?

Please give us the actual resistor values (for R1 and your fixed R2, and the resistance range of your adjustable R2), and check for which power or current they are rated.

"output voltage keeps decreasing."  What degree of change are you seeing, and over what period of time?  Is Vout drifting up and down slowly, say, a few mV over several minutes, or is the change faster, & monotonic?

Also, I assume you did, but maybe you simply didn't: did you take your adjustable resistor, connect it to a multimeter and see whether it has a stable resistance?

@Marcus Müller   R1 is a fixed 0.5 watt 120 Ω resistor. As to R2, I have used different fixed resistors for getting different output voltages and all of them worked well. My adjustable resistors (multi-turn, potentiometer) are 10KΩ but have no power or current rating written on them. I have not drawn high currents from this circuit. The point is that even when I draw currents as low as 20mA (4 volt, 0.08 watt) output voltage decreases.

@Fabio Barone In trying to find the cause of the problem, I measured my variable resistors with ohmmeter. Their value decrease 0.1 Ω per 50-60 seconds. I will edit my original post and add this information to it.

@Marcus Müller Before I see your comment "Also, I assume...", in trying to find the cause of the problem, I measured my variable resistors with ohmmeter. Their value decrease 0.1 Ω per 50-60 seconds. Nevertheless, I appreciate your precise comment.

There are a number of problems, all related to the size of R2.
Firstly, there are 50μA of current flowing from the ADJ pin down through R2 to ground. Search for "ADJUST terminal current" on page 6 of this datasheet. Whatever current is flowing from the output down through R1 and R2 must be orders of magnitude greater, for the formula to work:
$$ V_{OUT} = 1.25V \times \left( 1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1} \right) $$
That means current in R2 must be milliamps, not microamps, and 10kΩ is way too large for that. Typically, R1 and R2 are hundreds of ohms, not kilohms.
Secondly, without a load, you shouldn't expect regulation to be very good, unless you also satisfy a condition described as "Minimum load current
to maintain regulation", on page 6. It say 3.5mA, or worst case, 10mA. When no load is present, you must have 3.5mA of output current anyway, which must flow via R1 and R2. The only way to guarantee that is to have R1 and R2 small enough:
$$ \frac{V_{OUT}}{R_1 + R_2} > 3.5mA $$
Your R2 (10kΩ) is way too large to satisfy that condition.
Lastly, since the value of R2 is typically of a similar order of magnitude to R1, you would need \$R_2 \approx 100\Omega\$ (or at most a few hundred ohms). That places your potentiometer wiper very near to its end of travel, in a region where you have very little control. I suspect that temperature changes are causing the wiper to move very slightly, and that's enough for a few ohm's of drift. Over the full 10kΩ range it's not much, but when you require a precise value near 100Ω, it's a mile.
Use a potentiometer which covers the range of resistance you require.

@ Simon Fitch. You said "Typically, R1 and R2 are hundreds of ohms, not kilohms". This raises a problem: if we want 37 volts out of lm317, and R1 is 120 ohm, then R2 must be 3.432 Kohm.

@SAA OK, I should have said typically R1 and R2 are chosen to pass 5mA or so of current. Typically, though, these regulators are providing 3V to 15V, not 37V. At 37V out, sure R2 is going to be larger.

Consider this multiturn pot.
It has maximum power dissipation of 0.5W and tempco of 100ppm/°C.
With R1=120 ohm and the usual 1.2V between output and ADJ on LM317 this means 10mA will flow through the potentiometer.
Now suppose you set the output to 10V, there will be 8.8V on the pot, so it will dissipate only 88mW... way below its 500mW maximum... should be fine, right?
Well... no. Because they're 10kOhm pots, so you're only using a tiny part of the resistive track. If the pot is set to 880 ohms to get 10V output, then it's only using 880/10k=8.8% of the track to burn those 88mW. This is the same power density (Watts/area) as if the whole pot was burning 1W.
The maximum dissipation is 500mW, but that's for the entire track. If you turn it down, maximum allowed dissipation goes down too because the amount of track available to burn that power also shrinks. If the track is on a thermally conductive substrate, it may work, but if it is not, then it may overheat.
Note the 100ppm/°C tempco specified in the datasheet does not mention if the error is in proportion to the pot's setting, or in addition. If it's the latter, which would be logical as it would also account for wiper movements due to temperature changes, it would mean 100ppm of 10k, which is 1 ohm, per °C. If you use the 10k pot to get a very low value like 100 ohms, then 1 ohm/°C is a huge amount of error.
It's better to pick a pot value which results in the wiper being in the "upper half" of the track, as this reduces most sources of error and drift, and is much easier to adjust by hand. So for a 10k pot, lowest drift would be in the 5k ohms to 10k range.
I think your pot is simply getting too hot. With a 1k pot, it would work fine. Another option is to increase R1 to 1k2 to reduce current through the pot, then add a dummy load resistor on the output to ensure the minimum output current spec of LM317 is met.
Note that wiring the pot like you did is a bit risky: when the wiper loses contact, and they all do eventually, then the LM317 will output its maximum voltage and kill the rest of the circuit downstream. It is safer to add a Zener diode in parallel with your variable resistor to limit voltage in case the wiper loses contact.

@ bobflux. You said "It is safer to add a Zener diode in parallel with your variable resistor...". How much should the voltage and wattage of this Zener?

LM317 output voltage will be the voltage on ADJ pin plus 1.2V. If the pot loses contact, output will be close to input, which is a problem if you're powering something that can't take that voltage. If there is a Zener diode in parallel with the pot, this will set a maximum voltage on ADJ pin, so LM317 output will be Zener diode voltage plus 1.2V. So you can pick a diode with any voltage you want, to limit output voltage to a safe value, depending on what the regulator is supplying.

@ bobflux. You said "With R1=120 ohm and the usual 1.2V between output and ADJ on LM317 this means 10mA will flow through the potentiometer." My question is: To limit the current which flows through the potentiometer to 5mA, is it ok to place a 240 ohm resistor in R1? Or in LM317, R1 must be 120 ohm to allow 10mA?

LM317 has a minimum load, I think it's 10mA. Usually it is done with the 120R resistor, but you can also add a resistor from output to ground if you want to use a higher value than 120 ohms.
